# How to call a parse-cloud function in ember.js controller?

Tags: ember.js, parse-platform

I am working on a ember-cli app which fetch data from parse-cloud using [ember-parse-adapter](https://github.com/clintjhill/ember-parse-adapter) . It was working fine until recently i need to call a parse-cloud function in my ember controller. So, is there a way that i could use ember-parse-adapter to call parse-cloud function or any other approach to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way with the ember-parse-adapter BUT:

- You can make your own AJAX calls via jQuery `$.ajax` and the [Parse REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions)
- You can use the npm package for Parse.

  1. `npm install parse`
  2. Go to `node_modules/parse/build` and copy `parse-latest.js` to your `/vendor` directory
  3. Import into your app using Brocfile.js - app.import('vendor/parse-latest.js').
  4. The Parse namespace and [SDK](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions) are now available everywhere in your app.

Keep in mind both these approaches have security concerns as you will be making your API key available to anyone who inspects your app.